# azure vm script extension running till it times out

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Deploying a Linux VM in azure with custom script extension. It runs bunch of script in sequence till end, which I can see in the custom log. Even though script execution is finished deployment is in progress. Other deployment is getting delayed because of this. Any solution.

Comment: you block any traffic? whats the vm image?

Comment: Check the extension logs for information on processes

Comment: Does your custom script extension try to reboot the machine?